# can't create android project at intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, settings

I'm newly user at Intellij, and I want to use this IDE for creating android project.

I used scala SDK for Linux before and all was easy and intuitively.

Now I followed [Create a New Android Project](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Create+a+new+Android+project) by Jet Brains.

I used android sdk that was created for eclipse.

But when I created stuck project it can't resolve import statement:

[image: edit tab]

I tried configure at settings but it wasn't successfully:

[image: settings]

**How to configure this intellij settings on right way (with emulators and installed version)?**

Comment: You configured your Android SDK, but have you assigned it to your project/module? Select "Project" and make sure to choose Android SDK instead of Java SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Please use gradle build file to configure your project. The newer Intellij 13.0.2 has **File > New Project > Gradle: Android Module**

1. Download gradle from http://www.gradle.org/, unzip it and set **GRADLE_HOME** variable and **GRADLE_HOME/bin** to **PATH** variable
2. Check if gradle command works
3. Create a **build.gradle** file with the below text
4. Run **`gradle wrapper`**
5. In Intellij select **File > Import > build.gradle**

This should work for you.

**build.gradle file** (customize the below text as per your requirement):

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```